# Control number of cr.plot in one grid

Tags: r, plot

I have some troubles with the function `cr.plot`.

Here I attach my problem:

-First I run glm model with one dependent variable (Slope) and three independent (CPUEintra, Max.T, and Depth)

```
MODEL1<-glm(Slope~CPUEintra+Max.T.+Depth,data = na.omit(wiser_perc))
```

-Second I run the command `cr.plot()` to obtain each graph related to independent variables

```
cr.plots(MODEL1,line=TRUE,smooth=FALSE,grid=FALSE,
         col.lines="black",cex.lab=1.4,font.lab="2",cex.axis=1.5,ylab="Roach",lwd=3)
```

The output automatically show me three residual plots in accordance to number of independent variables.
What I want is to control the number of cr.plot in one grid  but it seems that the command `par()` does not work in `cr.plots`. Do you know any other command or solution for handling the number of cr.plots?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Maybe you find [this](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/car/docs/av.plot) interesting: the cr.plots is depreciated for crPlots, so maybe using crPlots will work well with `par()`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, `cr.plots` is depreicated in the `car` package. You may want to run `update.packages("car")` to get the latest version.

The "updated" version `crPlots` has a `layout=` parameter that allows you to control the number of rows and columns for the grid where the plots are drawn.